# How to list a paper in a CV that has been presented at a conference and submitted to a journal?

Tags: publications, cv

Is there an elegant way to state that a paper in a CV that has been presented at a conference and also submitted to a journal?

I.e. Name. Title. (Presented at XX Conference, Submitted to YY Journal)

Comment: Does "presented" mean that it's published in the conference proceedings, or that you read it (for a humanities paper), or just that you gave a talk/poster related to the work currently in submission?

Comment: It was presented in a conference session and is not in the conference proceedings. It was supposed to appear in a special issue of a journal related to that conference stream. However, the special issue will not be published and the paper is submitted to another journal now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A common approach is to have separate sections in your CV listing academics works by type. I.e., thesis, peer reviewed journal articles, peer reviewed full text conference proceedings, book chapters, books, conference presentations, etc.

Particularly for early career researchers, it is common to also include journal articles that are under review. These should be presented in a section distinct from published journal articles and should generally indicate what stage of review they are in (e.g., submitted, revise and resubmit, etc.). It is also often useful to make each section a numbered list, so readers can quickly ascertain how many works you have of each type.

Using this approach you would **list the journal article under the journal article section of your CV (or in the "submitted journal articles" section as the case may be) and  list the conference presentation under the conference presentation section of your CV.**

Typical readers of an academic CV will know how to interpret this.
In general (and this may vary by discipline), journal articles (and other full-text works) speak to your lasting academic contribution. In contrast, conference presentations show that you are actively presenting your work. Typically, people evaluating your CV (e.g., for a job, promotion, grant, etc.) would give different weight to different sections. Thus, organising your academic output by sections makes their job easier.